# <li> not populating name from firebase

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, firebase

```html
<div data-role="content" data-theme="" id="main" role="main">
  
  <div data-position="fixed" data-role="footer" data-theme="a">
   <div data-role="navbar">
    <ul>
     <li>
      <a class="font-new ui-nodisc-icon loader-class" data-textonly="false" data-textvisible="true" data-iconpos="notext" onclick="$(location).attr('href', 'iprefs.php')" data-icon="home" href="#"></a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a data-icon="flat-menu" class="font-new ui-btn-active loader-class" data-textonly="false" data-textvisible="true" onclick="location.reload();"></a>
     </li>
     <li>
      <a data-icon="flat-settings" class="font-new loader-class" data-textonly="false" data-textvisible="true" onclick="$(location).attr('href', 'settings.php')"></a>
     </li>
    </ul>
   </div>
  </div>
 </div>
 <script>$('#main').append('<ul data-filter-reveal="true" data-filter="true" data-role="listview" data-inset="true" id="applist"></ul>');</script>
```

hello i have this app and im trying to populate li's with the names from my firebase database but its creating the li but nothing inside them for name

```html
var list = $('#appList');
    var url = firebase.database().ref('/');
    url.on('value', getAppList);
    function getAppList(packages){
        var fbAppList = packages.val();
        var childRef = url.child('/');
        childRef.once('value', function(snapshot){
            snapshot.forEach(function(child){
                var $name = child.val().name;
            });
        
            $.each(fbAppList, function(i, app) {
                console.log(name);
                $('#applist').append($('<li>').append('<a href="">'+ name +'</a>'));
                $('#applist').listview("refresh");      
            });
        });      
    };
```

Comment: You have not defined a `name` variable within the scope of the `'<a href="">' + name + '</a>'` expression

Comment: @phil i defined the name val from up above var name = child.val().name

Comment: No you didn't. You defined `$name` and even then, only in the scope of that `forEach` callback

Answer (score -1):

What about change code $('<li>') to $('li')
See [the jQuery element selector](https://api.jquery.com/element-selector/)

Comment: `$('<li>')` creates a `<li>` element (wrapped in a jQuery object). Similar to `$(document.createElement('li'))`

Comment: it deletes my whole ul and li's i included the store.php code above if you want to take a look